# EWS Push Subscription using PHP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, exchangewebservices

Does anyone know how to respond to EWS (Exchange Web Services) Push Notifications using PHP.

I have initiated the [EWS Push Subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa566188%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx#sectionSection3) but cannot seem to send the correct SOAP response (in order to keep the subscription alive) when EWS sends my service a SOAP notification.

Taken from [this](http://www.thesoftwaregorilla.com/2010/04/exchange-web-services-subscriptions-and-notifications/) page, I was under the impression that my SOAP response should be as follows:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s= "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <SendNotificationResult xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
            <SubscriptionStatus>OK</SubscriptionStatus>
        </SendNotificationResult>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

However, EWS doesn't seem to be accepting my response as valid.

I have tried the following 2 code snippets with no luck:

**Respond using a SOAP string with Content-Type header**

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8' );

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'.
'<s:Envelope xmlns:s= "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'.
    '<s:Body>'.
        '<SendNotificationResult xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">'.
            '<SubscriptionStatus>OK</SubscriptionStatus>'.
        '</SendNotificationResult>'.
    '</s:Body>'.
'</s:Envelope>';
```

**OR Respond using a SOAP service**

```
class ewsService {
    public function SendNotification( $arg ) {
        $result = new EWSType_SendNotificationResultType();
        $result->SubscriptionStatus = 'OK';
        return $result;
    }
}

$server = new SoapServer( null, array(
    'uri' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
));
$server->setObject( new ewsService() );
$server->handle();
```

It might help to know that the classes I am using in my code come from the [PHP-EWS library](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I also posted a more specific question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25392228/799588), but have had no responses so thought I would ask whether someone has actually gotten this working using any method.

Comment: Do you know where the incoming push messages are documented?

Comment: @simbabque This was too long ago to remember. You'll have to Google for it but with their implementation of a REST API for 365 I wouldn't bother with SOAP implementations any more. Unfortunate if you're stuck supporting legacy versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem that I was close but needed to include the NotificationService.wsdl when instantiating the SoapServer class. The WSDL then allows that SoapServer class to format the response accordingly.

```
$server = new SoapServer( PHPEWS_PATH.'/wsdl/NotificationService.wsdl', array(
```

The WSDL was not included in the php-ews library download, however it is included with the Exchange Server installation. If like me you don't have access to the Exchange Server installation you can find the file [here](https://code.google.com/p/nginn-exchange/source/browse/trunk/ExchangeIntegration.Service/EWS/NotificationService.wsdl?r=2). I also had to add the following to the end of the WSDL because I was storing the WSDLs locally and not using autodiscovery:

```
<wsdl:service name="NotificationServices">
    <wsdl:port name="NotificationServicePort" binding="tns:NotificationServiceBinding">
        <soap:address location="" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

So the full working PHP code is as follows:

```
class ewsService {
    public function SendNotification( $arg ) {
        $result = new EWSType_SendNotificationResultType();
        $result->SubscriptionStatus = 'OK';
        //$result->SubscriptionStatus = 'Unsubscribe';
        return $result;
  }
}

$server = new SoapServer( PHPEWS_PATH.'/wsdl/NotificationService.wsdl', array(
    'uri' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'].'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
));
$server->setObject( $service = new ewsService() );
$server->handle();
```

Which gives the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:SendNotificationResult>
            <ns1:SubscriptionStatus>OK</ns1:SubscriptionStatus>
        </ns1:SendNotificationResult>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Hope that helps someone else because that took me a while to figure out!

Comment: How does SOAP talk with Exchange without login parameters in your example?